# How do make button smaller?

Tags: android, xml, button

How do I make this `ExtendedFloatingActionButton` smaller? In a normal FloatingActionButton I always used `app:fabSize="mini"` and it always made it small perfectly.
Here, `app:fabSize="mini"` has no effect

```
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal">      
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="heelo w"
          app:icon="@drawable/myicon"
          android:layout_gravity="end"
          app:fabSize="mini"/>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand it correctly, but can you set the layout width and height a custom dimension? Unless you don't want to specify it?

Comment: @ndriqa this doesn't work because it does not scale down the button's text & image accordingly

Comment: Does `fabCustomSize` work? As I can see in the documentation, FAB has a `setCustomSize` method. Can you also try to set it to 40dp programatically if that doesn't work, since 40dp is the dimension used when `fabSize` `MINI` is used?

Comment: `app:fabCustomSize` has no effect at all

Comment: Can you post more code? Or at least the parent of the EFAB xml tag?

Comment: @YnempKski Why don't you use a combination of textSize and iconSize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the `android:text` attribute use `app:collapsedSize` instead of `app:fabSize` like so:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:icon="@drawable/myicon"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    app:collapsedSize="40dp"/>
```

But if you want to show the text and the icon both you need to change the scale using `android:scaleX` and `android:scaleY` attributes. Here is an example:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:scaleX="0.5"
    android:scaleY="0.5"
    android:text="heelo w"
    app:icon="@drawable/myicon" />
```

Using the same scale for both X and Y is better for getting the same ratio. To get a smaller scale the parameters should always be smaller than one. For example `0.4`, `0.5`, and `0.6`.

Comment: close enough, but the text gets "cut out" in the middle . ( i want   both the text and the icon)

Comment: I have edited my second solution. Please try it. @YnempKski